# Recovering the name of a variable in Maple

Tags: maple

I am programming a procedure in Maple. This procedure receive a list of vector fields (from the ``DifferentialGeometry'' package). I want that in the output they appear, together with the performed computations, the name of the vector fields introduced by the user.

During the procedure I refer to them by the name I have given to the parameter, but I don't actually know the "names of the variables". Is there a way to recover them? I have being looking for in the Maple documentation and in the DGinfo help, but I didn't get anything.

EXAMPLE ADDED

I have simplified the problem to the following. Consider the code:

```
with(DifferentialGeometry); 
DGsetup([x, u], M); 
X := evalDG(D_u*x+2*D_x); 

myproc := proc (var) 
  return evalDG(var+D_u) 
end proc; 

myproc(X)
```

The output is

[image]

But I want modify the code in such a way that the output were something like

X+D_u is 2 D_x + (1+x) D_u

That is, I want to use the name ("X") of the variable in the output, not only the value (2 D_x + x D_u).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is the (plaintext) Maple code to reproduce, ie. a small example with such a list of vector fields, in a procedure (your words) and an example of calling such a procedure. All using the DG package? Your description is vague and incomplete. Show an example of input, and state clearly what you want to see as output. Are you saying that the user will assign a VF to a name, and then pass that name to a procedure, and you want the procedure to show the passed name (and not just its assigned value)? I'm guessing there. I should not have to guess.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advise, I will modify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of handling your example.

```
restart;
with(DifferentialGeometry):
DGsetup([x, u], M):

myproc := proc(var::uneval) local evar;
  evar := eval(var);
  return evalDG(var+D_u) = evalDG(evar+D_u);
end proc:

X := evalDG(D_u*x+2*D_x):

myproc(X);

    X + D_u = 2 D_u + (1 + x) D_u
```

Here is a variant on that idea, with two such parameters on the procedure, but also handling then in a more general manner.

```
restart;
with(DifferentialGeometry):
DGsetup([x, u], M):

myproc := proc(var1::uneval, var2::uneval)
  local evars, res;
  evars := [var1=eval(var1), var2=eval(var2)];
  res := var1 + var2 + D_u;
  return res = evalDG(eval(res, evars));
end proc:

X1 := evalDG(D_u*x+2*D_x):
X2 := evalDG(D_u*x+3*D_x):

myproc(X1, X2);

    X1 + X2 + D_u = 5 D_x + (1 + 2 x) D_x
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I guess that passing the parameter as "uneval" is the key. This way you can work with the "unevaluated" variable, i.e. with its name.